# UILabel vs. CATextLayer performance

Tags: ios, core-text

I wonder about the performance differences of using `UILabel` instances vs. CATextLayers in my table view cells. While `UILabel` is very convenient thanks to the support in interface builder and has some a additional features such as a way to provide a shadow, `CATextLayer` has access to more fonts and is supposed to be one layer(sic!) nearer to the graphics hardware. Btw., does anyone know whether `UILabel` might internally be using `CATextLayer`s?

To combine both the convenience and the access to more fonts, it might be possible to derive from `UILabel`, change the layer class to `CATextLayer` and configure the layer properties based on the label properties. If the label's `drawRect()` is empty, this should not have much of a penalty (apart from the additional `UIView` penalty), should it?

Comment: Why are you asking? Are you running into performance problems with your tableView? Have you ruled out other possible culprits?

Comment: The basic problem is getting access to the full font set that is available to CoreText (and CATextLayer) , which is not possible with a plain UILabel. I seek a way to combine the convenience of interface builder with the richness of the CATextLayer fonts.

Comment: I see. [CoreTextToy](https://github.com/schwa/CoreTextToy) from Jonathan Wight looks interesting.

Comment: FWIW, starting w/ iOS 5, the additional fonts formerly only available via CoreText are supported using the UIKit API.